# Count Group By Epoch Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, epoch

I used `DATEADD` to convert epoch time to a friend timestamp format. Now, how can I convert this timestamp into yearmon? or year or month? so I can apply `WHERE` and `COUNT` using `GROUP BY`.

I am on SQL Server 2012.

Here's the data sample:

```
Date        Class   Description
1420706286  1       Description1
1420706250  1       Description2
1420706228  2       Description1
```

I want to be able to count the epoch date into year and/or month format using `GROUP BY`. When I use `DATEADD(SECOND, Date, '1970-01-01 00:00')`, it formats it to a friendly datetime stamp format but it doesn't do well on filters.

Comment: Give some examples of how your data looks and what the desired output looks like.  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I added three rows of sample records.